# How to get a device details only using awk commands

Tags: linux, awk

Friends, I have `fdisk -l` output in one file called `test1.txt`.

Now I want to get the device name only using `awk`.

How to get a device name?

I want output like this:

```
/dev/sda1
/dev/sda2
/dev/sda3
/dev/sdb1
/dev/sdc1
```

Comment: The usual questions: What have you tried yet? What were your results?

Comment: I'd suggest dropping the `awk` bit from your question. As was stated on the other Q you asked with a similar title it isn't relevant. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117739/how-to-get-the-details-of-the-disk-and-partitions-using-awk-commands

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any reason to do this using fdisk and awk -- just get the device names from `/dev`:

```
printf '%s\n' /dev/[sh]d*
```

If you only want the partitions and not whole disks, limit the glob to look for a number in the name:

```
printf '%s\n' /dev/[sh]d*[[:digit:]]*
```

You can also query `/dev/disk`, but this may contain some devices you don't care about (the device mapper, for example):

```bash
readlink -f /dev/disk/by-id/*
```

Comment: readlink -f command not work

Comment: "Not work" in what way?

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '/^\/dev\// { print $1 }' test1.txt
```

Assuming this correlates to your `fdisk` output...